# How to send user data and its profile image using POST request from axios api to Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

```
User Data
let final_data = {
                'personal_data': {
                    'first_name': data.first_name,
                    'password': data.password,
                    'phone': data.phone,
                    'username': data.username,
                    'email': data.email,
                    'image': data.profile[0]
                },
                'address_data': {
                    "address_1": data.address_1,
                    "address_2": data.address_2,
                    "city": data.city,
                    "pin_code": data.pin_code,
                    "state": data.state,
                    "country": data.country
                }
           }
```

**Above Code is my form data which i have passed.
I had also tried to pass this data using json.stringify still it not works**

```
AXIOS POST Request
import API from "../Axios/AxiosService"
const registerUser = (data) => API.post(`registration/`, data)
export default { registerUser }

HEADERS
if (config.url = 'registration/') {
        requestOptions['headers'] = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyrV7KO0BoCBuDbTL', 'Accept' : 'application/json'}
    } else {
        requestOptions['headers'] = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem("access_token")) {
        requestOptions['headers'] = {"Authorization": "Token " + localStorage.getItem("access_token")}
    }
```

**Above Code is AXIOS POST Request and also Passed headers accrodingly. Using Application/Json i get all data except image and from data i also tried to pass data.profile instead of data.profile[0] but it didn't works.**

[Django Rest Framework error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFB2Q.png)

**In POST method of Django Rest Framework i had used below listed ways to get but in all methods i didn't get any data **

1. request.POST
2. request.data
3. request.Files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React inspite of passing **Content-type="multipart/form-data"** in to **POST** request it will not pass image object in backend.

So we have to convert whole data in to **formdata** and then pass in **POST** Request.

That's how I solved my error.

**[Have a look at the Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsiql.png)**

Answer (score 0):

You should give the queryset to `UserRegistrationView` like;

```
class UserRegistrationView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serialier_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: I have created UserRegistrationView specificaaly to register user so, it's not necesary to use queryset.

Still based on your suggestion i tried and it didn't worked.

Comment: In your post action did you return any Response ? like `return Response()`

Comment: yes, but I just send success code and message in return like below code

`return Response(
                {'status': 'Success', 'message': 'User Register Successfully', status=status.HTTP_200_OK)`